# Adding Data into JTable in SWING

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to design a medical prescription. My requirement is to design a table where user can insert data into it; just like user enters data into text fields.

Basically i need a table template, where user can insert data.

I have gone through JTable documentation and found that we can insert some static data in it. Please let me know if we can insert dynamic data into it or is there any way to create a table template to enter data.

Comment: It's been long I built a swing interface, but the way to do this is to use the Model object of the JTable, then invalidate the interface (JFrame) after each insert or delete.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: you should use property editable in jtable. In Netbeen Jtable property provide this property and we can also add textfield in our column( cell ).

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation of the most important basics how to work with JTable in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).